# Displaying Score System in Turing as String

Tags: string, text, integer, turing-lang

I'm working on a minesweeper clone game as a large project in my programming class. I know how to make a score system, but I'm having trouble displaying it.
I made it so that when the user presses a button, it adds 10 score. Originally the variable "score" is an integer, but I change it into a string because I'm using "Draw.Text" to display it. Otherwise, if I don't, it won't display properly because it erases a row of my background and won't use my font preset. Here's a picture of what it looks like and the code (I may have changed it a bit so it might not be exactly how I described it. The "What is your score" at the start is me trying to experiment.)

```
import GUI
setscreen ("graphics:800;800,title:TrapSweeper,nocursor")

var mypic :int := Pic.FileNew ("interface.bmp")
var safepic : int := Pic.FileNew ("safe.bmp")
var trappic : int := Pic.FileNew ("trap.bmp")
var font := Font.New ("Orator Std:27")
var font2 := Font.New ("Orator Std:10")
var score : int := 0
var username : string
loop
put "Welcome to TrapSweeper! What's your username? (Maximum 28 characters)"
get username
if length (username) > 28 then
put "The maximum characters for your username is 28."
delay(2000)
cls
elsif length (username) <= 28 then
put "What is your starting score?"
get score
exit
end if
end loop

cls 

procedure safe
Pic.Draw (safepic, maxx div 30, maxy div 30, picMerge)
score += 10
end safe

procedure trap
Pic.Draw (trappic, maxx div 30, maxy div 30, picMerge)
end trap 

Pic.Draw (mypic, maxx div 30, maxy div 30, picMerge)
Draw.Text (username, 280, 677, font, 55)
Draw.Text (intstr(score), 280, 727, font, 55)
var SAFE:int:=GUI.CreateButton(25,50,0,"safe",safe)
var TRAP:int:=GUI.CreateButton(25,25,0,"trap",trap) 

loop 
exit when GUI.ProcessEvent
end loop
```

[image]

```
     ^ The "safe" and "trap" buttons on the bottom left are experimental.
```